# Better way in adding sequence index in id attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3. I am using the `each_with_index` to generate the sequence:

```
<% @shops.each_with_index do |shop, i| %>
  <div class="item map-marker" id="shop_<%= i+1 %>">
```

I tried using `div_for`, but it takes the `shop.id` instead. Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: never found a better way for myself too...

Comment: Another approach would be to use the actual id of the shop, e.g. `id="shop_%<= shop.id %>"` -- it's unclear from your question why you need this.  If the ordering of what you're displaying is important (i.e. you're iterating over the divs in JS) then your solution is fine.  But if, for example, you want a permanent anchor URL that will scroll the browser to the right place regardless of which order the current view displays things, using the database id is the better approach.

Comment: I could use `div_for` to generate it with `shop.id`, but that's not what I want. I need the sequence index.